# How can i use libboost1.54-all-dev:amd64 and I386 together?

Tags: c++, boost, g++, x86-64, i386

I have a C++ Program which needs the program_options library from the libboost package.

I installed boost with `sudo apt-get install libboost1.54-all-dev` and then i compiled my program with

`g++ program.cpp -m64 -static -lboost_program_options -o compiled/program.out`.

Everything worked fine.

Then i wanted to compile it for 32bit so i used `-m32` instead of `-m64`.

It said:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libboost_program_options.a when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.a when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then i used Google and i found, that i have to install the boost i386 package for compiling i386 applications. But it seems, that i cant install amd64 and i386 the same time. When i try to install i386 apt-get want to remove the amd64 packages and when i try amd64 then i386 will be removed.

I can compile my apps in i386, but i have to install i386 and then reinstall amd64...

Hope anyone can help me with this! Thankyou!

Comment: Use version 1.55, the 386 and amd64 versions can now be installed together (at least on debian, you didn't specify your OS), if you install per package: not the -all one, but libboost-program-options1.55-dev for instance.

Comment: ah yes i am on debian thx for the tip, ill check it out...

Comment: hmm. it isnt looking like the 1.55 versions are in my repo... i am using debian jessie on linux mint debian edition...

Comment: 1.55 is available in debian testing and unstable (I don't know anything about mint).

Comment: mint is based on debian testing... can u give me the exact package name?

Comment: ah okay i added the official debian repository testing to my sources.list... now i installed libboost-dev-all:amd64 and it works fine and it was 1.55. but when i try to install the same package for i386 following error comes:

Comment: libboost-all-dev:i386 : depends on: libboost-mpi-dev:i386
                         depends on: libboost-mpi-python-dev:i386
                         depends on: libboost-python-dev:i386

Comment: I told you not to install the -all package but just libboost-program-options1.55-dev:i386 and libboost-program-options1.55-dev:amd64 (and similarly for others if you need them). Most boost packages are now multiarch but not all, and in particular not the python one.

Comment: omg... i removed evryting and installed the libboost-program options1.55.... itw anted to update libc and i said yes. but then o command works after this and after a restart i got kernel panic because itc ant launch the init... i reinstalled my system and now i have a new fresh debian. so, u say i should install libboost-program-options1.55-dev:i386. okay. and the amd64 version? only this package too?